# Handling gRPC requests with client-stream and/or server-stream in mezzio-swoole (PHP), is it possible?

Tags: php, grpc, mezzio, swoole

The framework is Mezzio and the server is Swoole, both the latest version.

Please note that Mezzio is just an example but Swoole is the main case.

When a request is arrived, swoole onRequest event is triggered and EventDispatcher dispatches the event to the relevant event, which in this case is RequestEvent. Then, RequestHandlerRequestListener converts the swoole request to a Psr7Request in order to handle it using a middleware or handler of mezzio. Finally, the response is emitted and the end() method of server is called.

So, what if the request is a gRPC request with stream client and/or stream server mode. In this case when a request is arrived with options, the swoole server should awaits for subsequent messages and based on server unary or stream mode, returns the response.

I want to know, can the swoole-server handle stream requests and stream responses for a gRPC communication?

Comment: This [repo](https://github.com/swoole/grpc) in the Swoole namespace shows an implementation for both client and server streaming, so my guess is yes, although I haven’t tried it.

Comment: I found [this page](https://github.com/swoole/swoole-src/issues/3901) in which developers have antithesis ideas about supporting client/server stream call/read. But I am curious if there is any way to workaround?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet, or are you still at the researching phase?

Comment: @Chris Hass , Yes, I have. I have implemented Swoole with Mezzio, so that Swoole server receives and responds to the http2 requests. The problem is with the stream (of messages) request. When I call the endpoint with client streaming request, Swoole only responds to the last message, and also the response is not of the type application-grpc.